# Open source bookmarks (and links) to social profiles

Tags: web, social-networks, contact-manager

I'm looking for an open source bookmark CMS with links to social tools. I want to allow users to publish, arrange and share contacts at different sites with links (link to Facebook, Instagram, and customs sites like forusm)

Like https://dan.tel

Can you please suggest the CMS? Thank you